# New to Javascript, writing a basic function

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript code:

```
var num1;
function press_Button(){
    num1 = 3;           
}
```

Then I have a button with this: `onclick="press_Button()"`

and in the HTML is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(num1);
</script>
```

The page displays the variable as undefined, even after hitting the button, and I can't figure out why.

Help!

Comment: The simple explanation: Because `document.write(num1);` is executed before `press_Button` is called (you clicked the button). `num1` does not have a value yet at this moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to update the display of num1 after you call `press_Button`.  What I would do is ditch the document.write, and instead make a span:

```
<span id="num1Display"></span>
```

And then:

```
function press_Button() {
    num1 = 3;           
    document.getElementById("num1Display").textContent = num1;
}
```

Or, if you need this to work on ancient browsers that don't like textContent, you could do:

```
function press_Button() {
    num1 = 3;           
    document.getElementById("num1Display").innerHTML = num1;
}
```

Comment: You can't just write directly like that? I just can't figure out why that wouldn't work? And I really appreciate you

Comment: @Axschech - no.  `num1` is just a javascript variable.  I mean, you *could* write its value out with `document.write`, but if you later update `num1`, then the value on the page will *not* update to the new value.  That's why you still see `undefined`, even though you've updated `num1`

Comment: but why was it displaying undefined even after I click the button?

Comment: @Axschech - see Guffa's answer - he explains it much better than I did

Comment: @Axschech: Because `document.write(num1);` is only executed once on page load (in your case). Considering printing a document (text file). Once you print it, the text on the paper won't magically change if you change the content in the document file. That's similar. I might be more apparent if you wrote `alert(num1)` instead of `document.write(num1)`. The alert is only executed once.

Answer (score 5):

That's because the `document.write` method turns the value into a string, which is written into the source code of the page.

Once the source code is written, there is no connection between the variable and the text in the source code. Whatever you do to the variable won't chance what was once written when the source code was created.

Whenever you update the variable, you also have to update the content in the page if you want the change to be visible. You can't change the source code after it is created, so you need an element that you can target, for example a span around the value:

```
<span id="num1Container"><script>document.write(num1)</script></span>
```

Use the `getElementById` method to get the element:

```
function press_Button() {
  num1 = 3;
  document.getElementById('num1Container').innerHTML = num1.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When document.write is called, num1 is undefined since the button has not been clicked yet. document.write is called once when the page loads, writes a string representation of the variable, then returns - its job is done. When the value of num1 changes, the displayed value does not change.

To modify the displayed value when the button is clicked, press_Button must modify the dom. See above answers.

I wouldn't recommend having inline onclick handlers on elements though. Use this instead:

```
<button type="button" id="button">Click</button>
```

Then your javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Code here
    }, false);
}, false);
```